# Apache shutdown unexpectedly?

Tags: xampp

Whenever I am trying to start my **apache** service it shows the system error.
How to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: reinstall Xampp. Make sure that you back up htdocs folder before uninstalling.

Comment: I am getting this error after new install of xampp latest version.
Again i reinstall and getting this error repeatedly..

Answer (score 0):

Follow this if reinstalling Xampp didn't work:

The program would not because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. The problem is that the Universal CRT which is part of the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio  failed to install.

Also try reinstalling Visual C++ Redistributable before moving ahead. If it still shows the error, go for the next series of steps.

Solution Install Windows Updates: 
Go to Start - Control Panel - Windows Update Check for updates Install all available updates. Install the updates and restart the PC. Check if any more updates are pending. If yes then install them too. If no then go ahead with the next step.

According to me, Visual C++ Redistributable comes along with Xampp Zip Package. If not download it from the following link:

For Windows 64-bit

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe

For Windows 32-bit

http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe

Run the vcredist_x64.exe (64-bit) or vcredist_x86.exe (32-bit) and select Uninstall Run the .exe again and select Install

Note:
You could also try running the vredist without updating installs. If it works then fine. Otherwise check for updates and then continue as explained above.

Do let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: No it is not working.I have to installed vcredist_x86.exe (32-bit) .But it remains same.Also I install all updates in my system.But no results.

Comment: Did ypu check for updates from windows?...Please install the updates. Remove vcredist first. Then uninstall Xampp. Check for updates. Install all the updates. After making sure that no more update is left, install Visual Redistributor, install vcredist and finally install Xampp.